# Using passportjs local strategy with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm having the hardest time trying to Figure out where I am going wrong with logging with using Passport with my React App

below is my code, I placed many console.logs to figure out where it's going. 
when I fire the log function from the web, it's able to hit 1, 2, and to the router at 3.

this is regardless of the input I put in the email or password. if I have the email in my database or not, or whether the password is correct or not. any help would be appreciated.

This is the login function from the react component

```
logIn () {
    console.log('111111111 log in fired')
    let user = {
      email: this.refs.email.value,
      password: this.refs.password.value
    }

    console.log('22222222222 created user', user)

    axios.post(`/users/login`, user)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('8888888888 got a response', res)
      if (res.data.message) {
        console.log('9a9a9a9a9a9a got an errorMessage')
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: res.data.message
        })
      } else if (res.data.user) {
        console.log('9b9b9b9b9b9b9 got a user back', res.data.user)
        window.location.href = '/#/Home'
      } else {
        console.log('9c9c9c9c9c9c9c9c got nothing back', res.data)
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: ''
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('88f8f8f8f8f8f8f8 got an error')
      console.log('axios error', error)
    })
  }
```

this is the user routes

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const db = require('./../models')
const User = db.User

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')

router.use(bodyParser.json({ extended: false }))
router.use(cookieParser());

const passport = require('passport')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const session = require('express-session');
const CONFIG = require('../config/config.js');

app.use(session(CONFIG.SESSION));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(email, password, done) {
    console.log('44444444444')
    User.findOne({
      where: {
        email: email
      }
    })
    .then(function(user){
      console.log('55555555555 user', user)

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res){
        console.log('666666666 compared password and hash')
        if(err) {
          console.log('EEERRRROOOOOOORRRRR', err)
          return done (err)
        }
        if (!user) {
          console.log('NNNOOOOOO UUUUSSSSEEEEERRRRR')
          return done (null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username'})
        }
        if (!res) {
          console.log('IINNVVAAALLLIIIDDDD PPPAAAAASSSWWWOOORRRDDD')
          return done (null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Password'})
        }
        console.log('77777777 user')
        return done(null, {user})
      })
    })
  }
));

router.post('/login', function(req, res){console.log('3333333333')},     
passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/Home', failureRedirect:'/LogIn', failureFlash: true}), function(req, res) {
  res.redirect('/Home')
})
```

again the console.log only hits 1,2, on the web side, 
hits 3 on the server side
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's in `res` ?

Comment: @AndyRay response

Comment: no, what is in it? what are you seeing in the logs? what is the status code and response text, if any?

Comment: @AndyRay now it's only hitting 1,2, and server 3

Comment: as of now, it doesn't go back to the web anymore, therefore, 8 and 9 doesn't get hit

Comment: Look at the network tab in chrome. What does it say for this request?

Comment: You need to return a response :)

Comment: @AndyRay the login says it's pending, and it stays like that until it throws an axios error back to the web for timing out.

Comment: @Mikkel although it doesn't even show that it's getting into the local strategy, doesn't show any console logs from 4,5,6,7,8,9. are you recommending i use return res.json instead of return done()? i tried to follow the docs as best as possible

Comment: @AndyRay I am also using webpack as my compiler, in the network after i click the login function, network shows status is "pending", type is "xhr", initiator is 'bundle.js', size is '0',

Comment: Well, you are doing a res.redirect, which I think means that the original request is not being completed. Do you need to do a res.ok(), and then use a `setTImeout` to do the redirect? Are you using React Router v4?

Comment: @Mikkel  i have react-router 3.2, but even before the res.redirect. i can't figure out how to get it into the console.logs within the localstrategy

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but it might be useful to someone. 
Passport verification callback expect to receive username and password as arguments. To change that we have to add options to LocalStrategy constructor:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email'
}, function(email, password, done) {
    // ...
   }
));
```